# Form post in iframe is redirecting parent to post URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I thought that if I created a hidden iframe and put a form inside of it, then submitted the form, it would submit in the background iframe and not affect the primary browser frame:

http://jsfiddle.net/gt7Xq/3/

If you're too lazy to visit the link (don't blame ya), this is what sequentially happens:

```
// DOM is ready
// create iframe element as child of document.body
// create form as child element of iframe
// create input type=file element as child of iframe form
// submit iframe form
```

However, what happens when the form is submitted is that the parent page is redirected to the POST URL of the iframe's form action attribute.

Why is this? What am I missing? I experience this same behavior in current version of Chrome and Firefox 4.

What I'm trying to do is upload a file in an Ajax-like manor. Unfortunately, there is no way of uploading a file using `XMLHttpRequest`. There's supposed to be a trick though—if you submit the upload in an iframe, it's suppose to upload in the background. I'm trying to achieve this, but have failed.

Comment: Which browsers have you tried? Is the behavior the same across them?

Comment: as far as i know form submission redirects the page your browser is located to a new destination. what you wanted to do is normally being achieved by using AJAX.

Comment: Question updated to reflect your comments. Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice to leave the question and how you solved it, so that if this question arises again the answer will be on file.

Comment: if you found the solution, post it as answer and accept it yourself, instead of erasing contents like this. rolling back now.

Comment: @YummyBánhMì Please post the solution so you can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a target attribute to your form tag?

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" target="_self">
```